# Do I need to synchronize in this situation

Tags: java, android, multithreading, listview

i'm making Android application. I have a class in which I get some orders every 30 seconds from database like this:

```
public class OrderScheduler {
    private List<OrderMain> orders = Collections.synchronizedList(
            new ArrayList<OrderMain>());
    ...
    private void main() {
        service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                orders = getStuff();
            }
        }, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Then there is an Activity class in which i create ListView with objects from above list like this:

```
newOrdersListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newOrdersListView);
    OrderScheduler os = OrderScheduler.getInstance();
    List<OrderMain> newOrders = (os.getOrders() == null) ? 
            new ArrayList<OrderMain>() : os.getOrders();
    ArrayAdapter<OrderMain> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<OrderMain>(
            this, R.layout.listview_row, newOrders);
    newOrdersListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

I read in javadoc when iterating over synchronized list i need to synchronize on it.

My question is when i click on some item of this listview, does the onItemClick method need to be in synchronized block ? I thought that when i choose some item from listview it basicly needs to iterate over the newOrders list.

By the way right now i don't synchronize this listener method and it seems to work. I dont create any more threads than the one in OrderScheduler in this application.
Thanks for some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `.getStuff()` method produces an entirely different list each time; and it looks like its result only has one consumer. Also, it looks like that consumer does not modify the result.

My suggestion would therefore be to use an [`AtomicReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html).

Your "producer" code would then do:

```
ref.set(getStuff());
```

and your "consumer":

```
List<OrderMain> newOrders = ref.get();
```

Your `ref` would be an `AtomicReference<List<OrderMain>>` shared between the producer and consumer.

Comment: Reference assigment is atomic in Java, so there is no need to overcomplicate it with AtomicReference. AtomicReference's main power comes from compareAndSet() and getAndSet(). It has no addition if you use set() and get() only.

Comment: @kupsef it is its atomic properties which make it useful in this case!

Comment: @kupsef also, "Reference assigment is atomic in Java" <-- NO. Unless you declare a reference as `volatile`, you have no such guarantee; and  unless I am mistaken, you cannot share a `volatile` reference outside of its declaring class.

Comment: Well, reference assigment IS atomic. Do some research if you don't belive:)

Comment: Ok i was a bit confused because i see it first time. I changed what you suggested and it seems to work fine. But i don't know what it exactly changes to my previous solution. Is it better ? Anyway great thanks!

Comment: @kupsef it is atomic _within the thread that assigns it_; that doesn't make it visible from _other threads_, save for the special conditions of `volatile`.

Comment: @10101101 it serves different purposes from your initial solution; wrapping a `Collection` using `Collections.synchronized*()` returns a reference to a same collection for which all operations are synchronized, but this _does not guarantee_ that the reference returned by this operation is visible by other threads; `AtomicReference`, however, guarantees that. There are other traps too, but that would be too long to explain here.

Comment: @fge I know how volatile works:) But that race condition when other threads reads the old value lasts for milliseconds. The schedule updates the content in every 30 seconds... do you really feel the need of AtomicReference?:D

Comment: @kupsef yes, certainly; like I said, `volatile` works well as long as you access it from within a same class; here, no guarantee. As to the cost, I trust the JIT entirely to find a shorter path at runtime!

Comment: @fge To be sure, if i would have some more threads and more consumers (but still not modify the original list outside OrderScheduler) then it would be better to use synchronized list ?

Comment: @10101101 why, if your consumers only iterate the list without every modifying it?

Answer (score 0):

With the current code you don't need to syncronizate anything because you create a `ArrayList` everytime (if you use an iterator because internally it will use the old ArrayList).

The reason you need to syncronizate the list while you iterate is because you could get a `ConcurrentModificationException` (Iterator don't allow you to any change to your list while reading it)

P.S I suppose `getStuff` creates a new `ArrayList` because you do `orders = getStuff();`, if you change your code to modify your ArrayList you will see the `ConcurrentModificationException` exception.

Comment: Thak you for your answer! Yes i don't change this list anywhere outside OrderScheduler, so i won't get this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself who is executing the onItemClick.

Its the main (UI) thead, so no matter what happens, how crazy/fast the user is, the events are processed serially (by the main thread).

Synchronization wouldn't have any effect.

Comment: Yes exactly as you said it's the user, so yes the main thread of this application. So you say that in my original solution, the list doesn't need to be synchronized list ?